# Sync TFS Group from MS Project to TFS

Tags: tfs, active-directory, synchronization, ms-project

Is it possible to synchronize a work item in a project plan in MS Project that it's `Assigned To` field is set to a TFS group? I know this works with AD groups, for instance:

Assigned To: `Administrators` -> works for AD groups

Assigned To: `[My Team Project]\Contributors` -> does not sync in MS Project

Comment: Do you mean MS Project or Project Server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only sync groups that MS project is aware of. Now I do not think that you can create a group in MS Project of `[My Team Project]\Contributors` so you will likely need to create a new AD Group to allow your data to sync with MS Project..